# JAVAFX: Is it more efficient to select node using lookup or link to controller through fx:id

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Is it more efficient to select a node that I have defined in my FXML file by using the `lookup('selector')` method. Or is it more efficient to create `fx:id` and use that to identify the node in the controller by `@FXML` directive.

Comment: "More efficient" in what sense?

Comment: In terms of speed and memory. Mainly memory.

Comment: Why do you care? Do you have a performance problem?

Comment: I have a large number of nodes connected together so I keep a references for each node with the node it is connected to (e.g a checkbox which shows or hides a gridpane). It is quite slow to render when I am in debug mode. I am wondering if the lookup method would speed things up due to there being less objects.

Comment: But there wouldn't be fewer objects: the objects need to exist on the heap, otherwise they wouldn't be part of the scene graph. There might be fewer references, but references are fairly negligible in terms of memory consumption. This is not a trade off that is going to fix any performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

From a processing point of you, using a reference defined by an `fx:id` is going to be more efficient than calling [`lookup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html).

From a memory point of view `fx:id` references take up very little memory, so concerns about memory use of one solution over the other are irrelevant.

Unless you do millions of such lookups every rendering pulse, it is unlikely to cause any kind of performance issue.  From your description (checkbox which shows or hides a grid pane), this is not the case for you and the cause of your perceived performance issue likely lies elsewhere.